# Data Synchronisation

Tags: dataset, data-preprocessing

What would be the ideal solution to syncing gps coordinates (511 data points) to another dataset (36913). This happens because the gps data does not sample at a consistent rate, and instead is event-based.

What I want to do is to up-sample the GPS coordinates to match the other dataset by producing duplicates of itself. What would be the best way to do this?

Using the images below as an example, I want to match up these two datasets using the timestamps. However, since the data is sampled at different rates, data needs to be interpolated in some way. What I want to do is to produce duplications of these data points, so the first row of data from the time 10:01:38 will be duplicated to match the rate from the data in the second image until 10:03:26.

GPS Data
[image: gps]

Accelerometer Data
[image]

Comment: This is rather broad (& somewhat unclear, as you mention). Can you provide some example data? Questions here should have short, self-contained factual answers. Your question doesn't look like that is possible. Perhaps you should expand.

Comment: Some clarification of what you actually mean by "syncing" and "up-sample" would be helpful, too.

Comment: Please see my edit, I've attempted to clarify the points using images.

Comment: That's good, thank you!  Wouldn't you want to *interpolate* the GPS coordinates rather than duplicate them?  (One can view duplication as a "zeroth order" interpolation, which opens up the question to considerations of *better* methods of interpolation.)  It can also be helpful to explain what these measurements mean.  For instance, are the GPS coordinates point-in-time readings or are they perhaps readings collected during the intervening periods (which means they reflect average position estimates)? Or why not integrate the accelerometer data?